# Html form not sending data in post request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to implement password reset using JWT. I am sending a password reset email to user with his ID and JWT in params. When user clicks this link, it redirects him to a password input page. This page is rendered by following function:

```
router.get('/resetPassword/:id/:token', function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.token ==null || req.params.id == null) return res.send('Invalid reset 
       password link');
  Organization.findById({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, org) {
       if (err) return res.send(err);
       if (!org) return res.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).send('No user associated with this 
                reset password link');
  org.decodePasswordResetToken(req.params.token, function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) return res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send(err);
  console.log(`${req.params.id} ${req.params.token}`);
  return res.send('<form action="/api/o/resetpassword" method="POST">' +
       '<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="' + req.params.id + '" />' +
       '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' + req.params.token + '" />' +
       '<input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Enter your new 
                password..." />' +
       '<input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />' +
    '</form>');
    });
  });
});
```

Above code contains the form that I am rendering to user. Now the problem is when user clicks and submit the form. The values from Form should be submitted to the following function but I am not getting any values in the body. Although I can see the data using GET request but post request body is empty.

```
router.post('/resetpassword', function(req, res) {
    const {id, token, password} = req.body;
    Organization.findById({_id: id}, function(err, org) {
      if (err) return res.send(err);
      if (!org) return res.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).send('No user associated with this 
        reset password link');
      org.decodePasswordResetToken(token, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) return res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send(err);
        // set password for this user
        org.password = password;
        org.save(function(err, org) {
          if (err) return res.send(err);
          res.send('Your password has been successfully changed.');
        });
      });
   });
 });
```

I am a beginner in HTML and JS. Sorry if this is a stupid mistake. :D

Comment: DO you have a body parser setup? express doesn't populate req.body itself, check for node module body-parser

Comment: I am using `app.use(bodyParser.json())`. Is there anything else I need to setup ?

Comment: By, default http forms are sending url encoded data in the body ```aaa=1&bbb=2``` use must specify specialy multipart, JSON is'nt in the HTTP standard, it used only by ajax requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For form data, you also need to use: **app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))** and then you will get the post data in req.body